# Battery drops from around 40% to 6% on Linux but not Windows

Tags: laptop, battery

I replaced the 56 wh battery in my laptop with a 97 wh battery. On Ubuntu or KDE Neon, the battery jumps from 40% to 6%, which means my battery life is equivalent to what it was with the old battery. I’d assume it’s a bad battery, but it works fine elsewhere.

The battery works perfectly fine on windows, giving me solid battery life. I haven’t fully verified it on solus, but it seems to work fine there too. What could be causing this?

Comment: Please specify your OS & release details. You mention a number, none with release details.  (*This is not a Linux support site; SE Unix & Linux provides that function*)

Comment: Usually, battery management is handled by the battery firmware, not the OS. At least, in my experience, which for the last few years has been with ThinkPads. 
You can install and use tlp to get really good battery stats (I hope), or try upower -d

On ThinkPads, the battery reports what it thinks the official capacity of the battery is, and what the firmware says is the maximum it can currently hold. Battery firmware is not perfect. To reset it, fully discharge and recharge. tlp has a calibration feature to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a replacement battery, then it'll be important to cycle the battery in Linux at least once so that the system can identify the new minimum and maximum numbers. To do so, do this *in Ubuntu*:

1. Charge the battery to 100%
2. Let the battery drain all the way to zero. Ignore all the warnings about low battery and make sure the thing is all the way to zero and does an ugly, hard shut-down
3. Charge the battery to 100% again

This is generally sufficient to give the OS the new min/max numbers for the battery